tkinter: Labels disappear when StringVar is set
i am trying to build a GUI to display different Parameters of a Process. For that matter i use Labels with static text for the names of the parameters and Labels with StringVar for the values as they change and need to be updated frequently.
The problem: As soon as a StringVar changes (is set through .set()) the other Labels with static text disappear.
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from py_openshowvar import openshowvar

# Import eigene Bibliotheken
import unveraenderliche
import veraenderliche
import schichtabhaengige

# Definition Variablen
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

# Globale

global istlayer
global istll
global sollll
global schichtString
global laserString


istlayer = 0
istll = 0.0
sollll= 0.0
currentlayer = 0


# Verbindung mit Kuka
client = openshowvar('172.31.1.147', 7000);
client.can_connect;
aktiv = str(client.read('$Pro_State1', debug=False))
aktiv = aktiv.strip("b'")
print("Programm aktiv")

# Funktion zur Aktualisierung der Daten
def refreshStats():
    aktiv = str(client.read('$Pro_State1', debug=False))
    aktiv = aktiv.strip("b'")
    global istlayer
    global istll
    global sollll

    if aktiv=="#P_ACTIVE":
        print("Programm aktiv")
    # Auslesen der veraenderlichen Variablen
        veraenderlichevar = veraenderliche.veraenderliche(client);
        istlayer = int(veraenderlichevar[0])
        istll = float(veraenderlichevar[1])
        triangx = float(veraenderlichevar[2])
        triangz = float(veraenderlichevar[3])
        #isttd1 = float(veraenderlichevar[4])
        #isttg1 = float(veraenderlichevar[5])
        isttd2 = float(veraenderlichevar[6])
        isttg2 = float(veraenderlichevar[7])
        istdg = float(veraenderlichevar[8])/2560
        sollvel = float(veraenderlichevar[9])
        istvel = float(veraenderlichevar[10])

        # Auslesen der schichtabhaengigen Variablen bei Schichtwechsel
        if currentlayer < istlayer:
            schichtabhvar = schichtabhaengige.schichtabhaengige(client)
            sollll = float(schichtabhvar[0])
            #sollhoehe = float(schichtabhvar[1])
            #sollbreite = float(schichtabhvar[2])
            if istlayer == 1:
                unveraenderlichevar = unveraenderliche.unveraenderliche(client)
                adaptll = float(unveraenderlichevar[0])
                adapta = float(unveraenderlichevar[1])
                adaptb = float(unveraenderlichevar[2])
                adaptc = float(unveraenderlichevar[3])
                adaptd = float(unveraenderlichevar[4])
                adaptp0 = float(unveraenderlichevar[5])
                #maxlayer = float(unveraenderlichevar[6])
                #solltd1 = float(unveraenderlichevar[7])
                #solltg1 = float(unveraenderlichevar[8])
                solltd2 = float(unveraenderlichevar[9])
                solltg2 = float(unveraenderlichevar[10])
                solldg = float(unveraenderlichevar[11])
                sollfokus = float(unveraenderlichevar[12])
        currlayer = istlayer

        #print("DG: "+str(istdg)+"/"+str(solldg))
        print("Geschw.: "+str(istvel)+"/"+str(sollvel))
        print("Laserleistung: "+str(istll)+"/"+str(sollll))

    schichtString.set(str(istlayer) + "/" + "-")
    laserString.set(str(istll) + "/" + str(sollll))
    app.after(500, refreshStats)
# Aufbau GUI

class LMDVisualizer(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="icon.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "LMD Visualizer")
        tk.Tk.geometry(self, "1900x1100+1913+0")
        
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):


        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

        
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Monitoring",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()


        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Exit",
                            command=lambda: quit())
        button3.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        global schichtString
        global laserString
        schichtString = tk.StringVar()
        laserString = tk.StringVar()
        self.errormsg = tk.StringVar()

        # Label zur Darstellung der Triangulationsdaten
        self.triangLabel = tk.Label(self)
        self.triangLabel.place(x=1375, y=575, height=520, width=520)
        self.triangLabel.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.triangLabel.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.triangLabel.configure(anchor='w')
        self.triangLabel.configure(background="#00ff00")
        self.triangLabel.configure(compound='left')
        self.triangLabel.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.triangLabel.configure(font="-family {Segoe UI} -size 9")
        self.triangLabel.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.triangLabel.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.triangLabel.configure(highlightcolor="#000000")
        self.triangLabel.configure(relief="solid")
        self.triangLabel.configure(text='''''')

        # Label für den Kamerafeed
        self.camLabel = tk.Label(self)
        self.camLabel.place(x=1375, y=50, height=520, width=520)
        self.camLabel.configure(activebackground="#ffffff")
        self.camLabel.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.camLabel.configure(anchor='w')
        self.camLabel.configure(background="#ff0000")
        self.camLabel.configure(compound='left')
        self.camLabel.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.camLabel.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.camLabel.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.camLabel.configure(highlightcolor="#000000")
        self.camLabel.configure(relief="solid")
        self.camLabel.configure(text='''''')

        # Button zur Rückkehr ins Menue
        self.backButton = tk.Button(self)
        self.backButton.place(x=5, y=5, height=40, width=40)
        self.backButton.configure(activebackground="#ffffff")
        self.backButton.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.backButton.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.backButton.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.backButton.configure(font="-family {Segoe UI} -size 9")
        self.backButton.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.backButton.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.backButton.configure(highlightcolor="#000000")
        self.backButton.configure(text='''Back''')
        self.backButton.configure(command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        # Label zur Anzeige von Nachrichten (z.B. Warnungen)
        self.messageLabel = tk.Label(self)
        self.messageLabel.place(x=50, y=5, height=40, width=1800)
        self.messageLabel.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.messageLabel.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.messageLabel.configure(anchor='w')
        self.messageLabel.configure(background="#ffffff")
        self.messageLabel.configure(compound='center')
        self.messageLabel.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.messageLabel.configure(font="-family {Segoe UI} -size 9")
        self.messageLabel.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.messageLabel.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.messageLabel.configure(highlightcolor="#c0c0c0")
        self.messageLabel.configure(relief="solid")
        self.messageLabel.configure(textvariable=self.errormsg)
        self.errormsg.set('''''')

        # Button zum manuellen Beenden des Datenlogging
        self.stopButton = tk.Button(self)
        self.stopButton.place(x=1855, y=5, height=40, width=40)
        self.stopButton.configure(activebackground="#d70428")
        self.stopButton.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.stopButton.configure(background="#ff0000")
        self.stopButton.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.stopButton.configure(font="-family {Segoe UI} -size 9")
        self.stopButton.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.stopButton.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.stopButton.configure(highlightcolor="#000000")
        self.stopButton.configure(text='''STOP''')

        # PanedWindow als Container für Graphen und Daten
        self.panedWindow = tk.PanedWindow(self, orient="vertical", borderwidth=0, sashwidth=5)
        self.panedWindow.place(x=5, y=50, height=1045, width=1365)
        self.graphLabel = tk.Label(self.panedWindow)
        self.panedWindow.paneconfig(self.graphLabel, height=520, width=1365)
        self.panedWindow.add(self.graphLabel)
        self.graphLabel.configure(relief="solid")
        self.datenLabel = tk.Label(self.panedWindow)
        self.panedWindow.add(self.datenLabel)
        self.datenLabel.configure(relief="solid")

        # Inhalt des Graphen-Labels

        # Inhalt des Daten-Labels
        self.headerdatenLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Übersicht über Soll- und Istdaten", font=("Arial","30","bold"))
        self.headerdatenLabel.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4, pady=20)
        self.datenLabel.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.datenLabel.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.datenLabel.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.datenLabel.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        # Spalte 1
        self.layerTextLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Schicht:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.layerTextLabel.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W)
        self.llTextLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Laserleistung:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.llTextLabel.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.W)
        self.nahthoeheTextLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Nahthöhe:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.nahthoeheTextLabel.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.W)
        self.nahtbreiteTextLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Nahtbreite:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.nahtbreiteTextLabel.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=tk.W)
        self.fokusTextLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Fokusdurchmesser:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.fokusTextLabel.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=tk.W)
        # Spalte 2
        self.layerWertLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, textvariable=schichtString, font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.layerWertLabel.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.W)
        self.llWertLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, textvariable=laserString, font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.llWertLabel.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=tk.W)
        self.nahthoeheWertLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Drehzahl 1:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.nahthoeheWertLabel.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=tk.W)
        self.nahtbreiteWertLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Drehzahl 1:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.nahtbreiteWertLabel.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=tk.W)
        self.fokusWertLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Drehzahl 1:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.fokusWertLabel.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=tk.W)
        # Spalte 3
        self.td1TextLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Drehzahl 1:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.td1TextLabel.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=tk.W)
        self.tg1TextLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Durchfluss 1:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.tg1TextLabel.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=tk.W)
        self.td2TextLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Drehzahl 2:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.td2TextLabel.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=tk.W)
        self.tg2TextLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Durchfluss 2:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.tg2TextLabel.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=tk.W)
        self.dgTextLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Düsengas:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.dgTextLabel.grid(column=2, row=5, sticky=tk.W)
        # Spalte 4
        self.td1WertLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Drehzahl 1:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.td1WertLabel.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=tk.W)
        self.tg1WertLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Durchfluss 1:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.tg1WertLabel.grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=tk.W)
        self.td2WertLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Drehzahl 2:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.td2WertLabel.grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=tk.W)
        self.tg2WertLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Durchfluss 2:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.tg2WertLabel.grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=tk.W)
        self.dgWertLabel = tk.Label(self.datenLabel, text="Düsengas:", font=("Arial", "20"))
        self.dgWertLabel.grid(column=3, row=5, sticky=tk.W)


app = LMDVisualizer()
app.after(10, refreshStats)
app.mainloop()
client.close()

GUI before updating StringVars():

GUI after updating StringVars():


Avoid creating label as child of another label.  Create label as child of frame instead.

Is it possible for you to make a smaller example? That's an awful lot of code. For example, is matplotlib really required to reproduce this problem? See [mcve]

Do you mean self.errormsg has diasppeared?

Here is an example of what happens when you try to use a label as parent of another label(which you should avoid), this example shows a label been updated by second
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime


class App(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('100x100')
        self.title('Example Window')

        self.datetime_here = tk.StringVar()
        
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self).pack()
        self.parent_label = tk.Label(self, text='Inital text').pack()

        self.label_fixed_parent = tk.Label(self, text='Parent Fixed Text').pack()
        self.label_fixed_frame = tk.Label(self.frame, text='Frame Fixed Text').pack()
        self.label_fixed_label = tk.Label(self.parent_label, text='Label Fixed Text').pack()
        self.label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.datetime_here,relief='sunken').pack()
        
    def recall(self):
        self.datetime_here.set(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
        self.after(1000, self.recall) ## 1000 = 1 second

                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.recall()
    app.mainloop()


Note that self.frame = tk.Frame(self).pack() will assign None to self.frame.   Same for those labels.
